# red square in Eclipse project browser

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, java-platform-module-system

In an m2e project I was trying to introduce a specific module-info.java below src/test/java. In addition to the one below src/main/java.

Whether or not this is a good idea, I got a red square tagging the src/test/java folder.
I wonder what it means. Hovering over did not give a hint.

Comment: That's a bad idea since both targeting the same `.class` file. All problems, including problems without a specific file location like in this case, are shown in the _Problems_ view.

Comment: @howlger 1. I was trying to achive [this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html). How is that possible without 2 module-info.java? 2. I see the Problems window, but there is no entry with the Path of the project showing the red square.

Comment: 1. Either create a test project (when you want to test the module as module) or in the test source folder delete your `module-info.java` (when you want to test module internals). 2. The error message is _"The project was not built due to "Build path contains duplicate entry: 'module-info.java' for project..."_